# Find longest file in the project IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

Hello I want to know any trick or shortcut by which one can know which is the longest file in project.
i.e which file has the longest lines of code.Is there any shortcut or plugin available?

Answer (score 9):

I believe the OP was asking about the length of file, not the length of single line. You can try with such iteration:

```
(.*\n){100,}

(.*\n){1000,}

(.*\n){10000,}
```

Comment: What are you supposed to do on a standard unconfigurable IntelliJ setup when you run into `'(.*\n){10000,}' produced stack overflow when matching content of the file`?

Answer (score 1):

Although this is kind of hacky it still works.

You can search your whole project using the regex repetition pattern. Just right-click your project folder in the project structure view and choose "Find in path...". Be sure to check "Regex" in the search window that appears.
So you'll start out and match any line with any length in your project

`^.$`

(If you're not familiar with regex: ^ and $ are used to denote the beginning and end of a line and . matches any character)

Then you gradually increase the number of matched repetitions

`^.{1,}$`

`^.{10,}$`

`^.{100,}$`

`^.{1000,}$`

(You use {start, end} to indicate to interval of repetitions. If you leave end blank it will match anything from start)

Using this you will soon be left with the longest line(s) in your project.

As I said it's kinda hacky but it's also quick and works if you don't have to automate the task.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: hello @DavidBauer thank you for your answer but it will find the longest length of the line not the file.I want to find the longest file int my project that means which file has the longest line of code

Comment: Do you mean you want to find the file with the most lines of code or the file that contains the longest single line of code?